# Running a Macro in Google Sheets Using IF Function

Tags: function, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm currently creating a spreadsheet for work and am looking to create a way to navigate around the spreadsheet without having to find specific tabs.

What I'm after is as follows: let's say I have Page 1, Page 2, and Page 3. I would like a drop-down menu on Page 1 with the options Page 1, Page 2, and Page 3. And whichever I select from the list, a macro would run that automatically changes the page to the one selected in the drop-down.

Is this possible? I would imagine it might involve an IF function, but I can't quite work out what I would need to write in the function box to make this work. Thank you in advance for any advice/info.

I recorded a macro navigating to the page I wanted, but then got stuck at writing an IF function, it started as =IF(A1="Page 2"... then I got stuck, I can't figure out how to make it run a macro at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with an IF function**, but there might be some way that I'm not aware of.

If you have a dropdown with the choices in it on Sheet1 and it is linked to A1, then use the onEdit event and this code in apps script:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if(s.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==1){
    var tgt = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(e.value);
    tgt.activate();
  }

}
```

Where the if condition is that the piece of the workbook that changed was Sheet1, Column 1, Row 1 (Sheet1!A1), and if so it proceeds to the next bit, which is to get a reference to a sheet using the value of the dropdown* and then activate it.

* or rather, the value of Sheet1!A1. afaik, dropdowns have to be linked somewhere, as opposed to Excel which has a couple of different kinds of controls, some of which are linked to a sheet and some of which aren't.

** or maybe you can.  Now that I think about it you might be able to use HYPERLINK and the value of the dropdown to create a dynamic hyperlink, but I think you'd have to know the IDs of the tabs (from the URL) not the sheet name.  Apps Script is probably more straightforward.